# Objective-C Sorting an Array by the values of an inner Array

Tags: objective-c, sorting, multidimensional-array, indexing

I want to sort a NSMutableArray which has NSArrays with respect to the value at the index 1 of the NSArray. I'll try to draw a picture of arrays.

```
NSMutableArray *ultimateHighscoreArray = { 
    ( (NSString) userName, (double) score, (int) numOfCorrectAnswers ) , 
      ( John , 4.5 , 3 ) , 
      ( Terry , 7.5 , 1) , 
                                     ... }
```

The first array within the NSMutableArray is an example which shows how examples are located. Second and third are how the values actually are. So, what I want is to sort these arrays having the array containing higher value at first index to go higher up in the ranking. For this example the array that has 7.5 which is Terry Array should go before the one that has 4.5 . I want the results to be held in a NSMutableArray in decreasing order. Thank you.

Comment: I have a feeling that your array should contain instances of a custom class, or at the very least NSDictionary...

Comment: While I agree that perhaps you should restructure your data I've posted an answer for your current structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
[ultimateHighscoreArray sortUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSNumber *score1 = [obj1 objectAtIndex:1];
    NSNumber *score2 = [obj2 objectAtIndex:2];

    // Reverse the comparison here (compare score2 to score1)
    // in order to get a descending order
    return [score2 compare:score1];
}];
```

A general advice: your data structure would be clearer if it were an array of `NSDictionary` instances or even an array of custom objects (e.g., your custom `Score` class). In those cases, you could also use `NSSortDescriptor` to sort the array, which would result in cleaner, easier-to-read code.

Comment: Your answer is nearly perfect. It worked to some point. Most of them are in the right order however some of them are not. This is weird. Do you have any guess what went wrong?

Comment: Can you give an example of the records that did not sort in the correct order?

Comment: Nevermind :) The error was most likely because of corrupt data from earlier experiments. I deleted the memory and now it sort perfectly. If I see another error like that I'll post it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

The `sortUsingComparator:` method allows you to sort an array using a block, e.g.:

```
[ultimateHighscoreArray sortUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [[obj1 objectAtIndex:1] compare:[obj2 objectAtIndex:1]];
}];
```

For clarity, it would probably be better to use an array of dictionaries (or instances of a custom class) for this data structure.

Comment: Note that this will sort the array in ascending order of scores.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom comparator like this :)

```
[ultimateHighscoreArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSArray *arrayA = (NSArray *)obj1;
    NSArray *arrayB = (NSArray *)obj2;

    double scoreA = [arrayA objectAtIndex:1];
    double scoreB = [arrayB objectAtIndex:1];

    if (scoreA > scoreB) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else if (scoreA < scoreB) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}];
```

Comment: This won't work. The array doesn't contain `double`s but `NSNumber` instances.

Comment: Then just swap around the NSNumbers... I think the code is pretty straight forward to be edited.